# DELETE from mysql table and get informations about deleted rows with one query

Tags: mysql

I want to combine following two queries to one

first query:-

```
SELECT * FROM `same_table` WHERE `same_column`="same_string";
```

second query:-

```
DELETE FROM `same_table` WHERE `same_column`="same_string";
```

I'm new to mysql.

Comment: 1st: This is not a question, it's a statement. 2nd: How do you want to _combine_ them? Output entries, then delete them?

Comment: why  you want to combine the two query?  .. what's your goal?

Comment: There are questions like that on stackoverflow. Just type "return deleted row  mysql".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your goal is after select finished you must delete the selected data. Use this query.

```
DELETE FROM `same_table` WHERE `same_column`="same_string" and (SELECT * FROM `same_table` WHERE `same_column`="same_string");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append the two queries together in a single query.  As long as you have the semi-colon separating them, they will both execute.

Example of a test DB I have running:  This is holding click numbers for some buttons I set up using AJAX.  I ran 2 queries basically similar queries to yours and I simply appended the two queries together.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM clicks;
+-----------------+------+---------------------+
| category        | num  | lasttime            |
+-----------------+------+---------------------+
| Five            |   13 | 2017-11-23 22:50:02 |
| One             |   25 | 2017-11-23 22:49:54 |
| Two             |   40 | 2017-11-23 22:50:00 |
| Three           |   60 | 2017-11-23 22:50:00 |
| Six             |    4 | 2017-11-23 22:50:02 |
| Seven           |    4 | 2017-11-23 22:50:03 |
| Eight           |   14 | 2017-11-23 16:28:19 |
| Four            |    7 | 2017-11-23 22:50:01 |
| Random Button 1 |   29 | 2017-11-23 16:40:31 |
+-----------------+------+---------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> SELECT num FROM clicks WHERE category='Random Button 1';
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|   29 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT num FROM clicks WHERE category='Random Button 1'; DELETE FROM clicks WHERE category='Random Button 1';
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|   29 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

After running `SELECT * FROM clicks;` again, this is the output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM clicks;
+----------+------+---------------------+
| category | num  | lasttime            |
+----------+------+---------------------+
| Five     |   13 | 2017-11-23 22:50:02 |
| One      |   25 | 2017-11-23 22:49:54 |
| Two      |   40 | 2017-11-23 22:50:00 |
| Three    |   60 | 2017-11-23 22:50:00 |
| Six      |    4 | 2017-11-23 22:50:02 |
| Seven    |    4 | 2017-11-23 22:50:03 |
| Eight    |   14 | 2017-11-23 16:28:19 |
| Four     |    7 | 2017-11-23 22:50:01 |
+----------+------+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So yes, you can have as many statements within the same query.  They just have to be separated by a semi-colon.

This also applies to PDO prepared statements, assuming you're doing this with PHP.

Comment: `As long as you have the semi-colon separating them` they are two queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought it would take more seconds than one statement. But times are same.